# Create calculated field based on previous rows Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a manually calculated column where I keep track of a current inventory.

Currently, I have a table that looks like this:

```
| Group        | Part | Operation Type | Transaction Amount |
|--------------|------|----------------|--------------------|
| Concrete     | A    | STOCK          | 100                |
| Concrete     | A    | Buy            | 25                 |
| Concrete     | A    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | A    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | A    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | A    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | A    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | STOCK          | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | Make           | -10                |
| Concrete     | B    | Make           | 150                |
| Construction | C    | STOCK          | 10                 |
| Construction | C    | Make           | -1                 |
| Construction | C    | Make           | -1                 |
| Construction | C    | Make           | -1                 |
| Construction | C    | Make           | -1                 |
| Construction | D    | STOCK          | 5                  |
| Construction | D    | Make           | -5                 |
```

The table is first ordered by `group` then by `part`, and then `STOCK` is always shown as the first value. The idea is to create a new manually calculated column, `curr_inventory`, that allows for us to keep track of current inventory and see if or when our inventory for a given part, for a given group, dips below 0.

Ideally, the end results would look like this:

```
|     Group    | Part | Operation Type | Transaction Amount | New_Inventory_Column |
|:------------:|:----:|:--------------:|:------------------:|:--------------------:|
|   Concrete   |   A  |      STOCK     |         100        |          100         |
|   Concrete   |   A  |       Buy      |         25         |          125         |
|   Concrete   |   A  |      Make      |         -10        |          115         |
|   Concrete   |   A  |      Make      |         -10        |          105         |
|   Concrete   |   A  |      Make      |         -10        |          95          |
|   Concrete   |   A  |      Make      |         -10        |          85          |
|   Concrete   |   A  |      Make      |         -10        |          75          |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      STOCK     |         10         |          10          |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      Make      |         -10        |           0          |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      Make      |         -10        |          -10         |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      Make      |         -10        |          -20         |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      Make      |         -10        |          -30         |
|   Concrete   |   B  |      Make      |         150        |          120         |
| Construction |   C  |      STOCK     |         10         |          10          |
| Construction |   C  |      Make      |         -1         |           9          |
| Construction |   C  |      Make      |         -1         |           8          |
| Construction |   C  |      Make      |         -1         |           7          |
| Construction |   C  |      Make      |         -1         |           6          |
| Construction |   D  |      STOCK     |          5         |           5          |
| Construction |   D  |      Make      |         -5         |           0          |
```

The end result would be a column that initiates when the part number has changed and the operation type is STOCK, and then begins to calculate (using the transaction amount) what the current inventory is.
I am not sure where to start on a SQL query that would allow for this. Intuitively, the pseudocode would look something like:

```
for each row in table:
    if operation_type == "stock":
        curr_inv = stock.value
    else:
        curr_inv = previous_curr_inv + transaction_amount
```

However, I am not sure how to even begin writing SQL for this. I typically try to post what SQL I am working with but I don't even know where to begin. I have looked at various posts online, on SO, including posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517940/sql-calculated-field-base-on-calculated-field), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268337/create-calculated-value-based-on-calculated-value-inside-previous-row), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776958/oracle-sql-calculate-value-using-previous-row), but I could not see how the selected answers could be used as a solution.

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the table seen above is the result of a previous table that creates it. Unfortunately I do not have access to the script that creates that table, I have only had the logic explained to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the window function to calculate the running total.

I added the row_number column in the subquery.

Try this:

```
select t1."Group",t1."Part",t1."Operation Type", t1."Transaction Amount",
sum(t1."Transaction Amount") over (partition by t1."Group",t1."Part" order by t1.rownumber)
from (
select row_number() over (order by null) as rownumber, t.*
from test t ) t1
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f2676e815798e6c0b94edcc3bb724c2)

Comment: This was absolutely correct. Thank you! Would you mind adding a little bit as to how this works so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @JerryM. Because you have duplicate values in transaction amount (For example, -10,-10...), the server does not know which one needs to be added first. In my subquery (t1), I added one virtual row number column as the primary key to tell the server the sum order.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  To put things in order, you need a column with the ordering.  In the code below, I will use `?` for this column.

Then you want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when operation_type in ('STOCK'),
                when operation_type in ('Make') then - amount
                when operation_type in ('Buy') then - amount
                else 0
           end) over (partition by group, part order by ?)
from t;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the answer. Your answer made me aware that I incorrectly phrased my question, which I'm afraid may make your answer invalid (though it solved the incorrect version of the question I posted). I have edited my question which may affect your answer.